# Find TableLeyout in a thread (Because of the ProgressDialog)

Tags: android, multithreading, tablelayout, progressdialog

On my activity, im getting some big data from web, and while getting this data i want to show the user a ProgressDialog with spinning wheel. That i can do only with putting this code into a thread, right ? 
the problem is that after im getting this data i need to insert it into my tableLayout as TableRows and it seems impossible to **access the TableLayout from the thread**.

What can i do to show this progress dialog and to be able access the table layout from the thread ??
Is there any event that happens on the end of the thread ?

My code fails for :

```
_tableLayout.addView(_tableRowVar, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
      LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
      LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
```

My full code is :

```
final ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MyActivity.this, "", 
            "Getting data.\nPlease wait...",true);

new Thread() 
{
    public void run() 
    {
        try
        {
            TableLayout _tableLayout;
            _tableLayout = (TableLayout)MyActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.tableLayoutID);

            List<String> data = getDataFromWeb();

            // Get the data and bind it into the table
            publishTableLayoutWithTableRows(_tableLayout, data );

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(MyActivity.this)
                 .setMessage(e.getMessage())
             .show();
        }
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
}.start();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [AsyncTask](http://www.screaming-penguin.com/node/7746)

you will also notice comments `can use UI thread here` next to the methods where you can use UI.